# Display an alert message if a checkbox is uncheck C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to create a design form in visual studio with 4 checkboxes and I really want to make the user to check only one of them, and if he's not checked one, when he will press a button, he should receive a notification with the obligation to select a box, and the program should not starting.

Comment: May be you want use a RadioGroup. Put into a Panel or GroupBox, or use the GroupName.

Comment: can you be more explicit please, about the code.

Comment: That's #1 in the GUI Bloopers book, use RadioButtons instead.

Comment: I added the "winforms" tag (as there are several different UI frameworks in .NET) and removed the "visual-studio" tag (which is reserved for questions regarding the development environment itself)

Comment: Checking one box in a group is exactly  what a RadioButton list is.

Answer (score 0):

`RadioGroup` is a control very similar in appearance to `CheckBox`. It's used to select only one `RadioGroup` in each group. You can define groups of radio buttons puttin inside a container (a `Form`, a `Panel`, a `GroupBox`). Add 4 radio buttons to your form, set the `Text` property.

You can check if a radio button is selected:

```
var isChecked = radioButton1.Checked;
```

Or make a method like this:

```
private int GetSelectedRadioIndex()
{
    var buttons = new[]
    {
        this.radioButton1,
        this.radioButton2,
        this.radioButton3,
        this.radioButton4
    };
    for (int i = 0; i < buttons.Length; i++)
    {
        if (buttons[i].Checked)
        {
            return i;
        }
    }

    return -1;
}
```

If you get a `<0` index, there aren't a radio selected. In other case you have a 0 index of the radio that is selected.

Answer (score 0):

As indicated, use a container like a `Panel` or `GroupBox` while with a GroupBox you can set a caption to indicate what the RadioButtons are for.

Create a private list in the form

```
private List<RadioButton> _radioButtons;
```

Subscribe to the Form's OnShown event, add the following code where `OptionsGroupBox` is a GroupBox with four Radio Buttons. This ensures no default selection which is optional.

```
private void OnShown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _radioButtons = OptionsGroupBox.Controls.OfType<RadioButton>().ToList();
    _radioButtons.ForEach(rb => rb.Checked = false);
}
```

Add a button to assert/get their selection.

```
private void CheckSelectionButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var selection = _radioButtons.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Checked);
    if (selection == null)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Make a selection");
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show($"You selected {selection.Text}");
    }
}
```

**Edit**: Working with both Panel and GroupBox

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace RadioButtonApp
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private List<RadioButton> _radioButtonsGroupBox;
        private List<RadioButton> _radioButtonsPanel;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Shown += OnShown;
        }

        private void OnShown(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _radioButtonsGroupBox = OptionsGroupBox.Controls.OfType<RadioButton>().ToList();
            _radioButtonsGroupBox.ForEach(rb => rb.Checked = false);

            _radioButtonsPanel = OptionsPanel.Controls.OfType<RadioButton>().ToList();
            _radioButtonsPanel.ForEach(rb => rb.Checked = false);
        }

        private void CheckSelectionInGroupBoxButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var selection = _radioButtonsGroupBox.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Checked);
            if (selection == null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Make a selection");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show($"You selected {selection.Text}");
            }
        }

        private void CheckSelectionInPanelButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var selection = _radioButtonsPanel.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Checked);
            if (selection == null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Make a selection");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show($"You selected {selection.Text}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: So, I was trying to do this I use panel, when I am pressing the button nothing appear on the screen.

Comment: Can't say why as there is no code to look at but the code I provided works with both GroupBox and Panel controls. I altered my reply to do both a GroupBox and Panel.

Comment: Thanks, I solve it with your solution.

Comment: Great, consider marking the reply as answered so others with the same or similar issue know this worked for you.